# Can't clone repository. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException:

Tags: redhat-brms

I am trying to clone repository which is in the folder in my system to Redhat BRMS, but unable to clone the repository due to the above error message. I searched for issue, but all answers are explaining about cloning from remote GIT. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you can experience problems with the git internal services because it listen on an IP address different from what you are using with your git client.

The solution is adding the following system property:

`<property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.host" value="0.0.0.0"/>`